# Normalizing skewness with the Power or Box-Cox Transformation

Tags: data-transformation, skewness, moments

Suppose I have a random sample drawn from an arbitrary strictly positive continuous distribution. Suppose moreover that I want to use the Box-Cox transform to zero out the skewness. Is there an explicit solution to the required value of the exponent lambda that can be calculated as a function of the skewness or any other sample statistic, or is it necessary to find it through numerical methods?

I have revised this question in light of Glen's comment to respect the allowable range of the Box-Cox

Comment: Box Cox only works on positive random variables (the parameter lambda might be -0.5, for example). So if you standardize your variable you won't be able to do Box-Cox directly on it.

Answer (score 1):

According to this: https://medium.com/@kangeugine/box-cox-transformation-ba01df7da884 , $\lambda$ needs to be calibrated by cross-validation.

Comment: Welcome to [stats.se].
Thank you for your answer.
Can you please [edit] you answer to expand it, in order to include the main points of the link you provide? It will be more helpful both for people searching in this site and in case the link breaks. By the way, take the opportunity to take the [Tour], if you haven't done it already. See also some tips on 
[answer], on 
[formatting help](https://stats.stackexchange.com/help/formatting)
and on writing down equations using 
[LaTeX / MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020).

Comment: @Ertxiem-reinstateMonica -- thanks for the guidance. If it's OK I'll keep it in mind for future posts, and this particular question is very old and the questioner is unlikely to still be interested.

Comment: I agree that andrewH might no longer be needing an answer, however, other people searching the site might be interested in an answer, in particular one that explains how to obtain $\lambda$. I'll provide the full quote for reference:
```The problem with the Box-Cox Transformation is estimating lambda. This value will depend on the existing data, and should be considered when performing cross validation on out of sample datasets. Make sure to estimate lambda according to the training dataset.```